# On predicting whether a real valued function has a non linear asymptote or not.

Tags: calculus, functions, special-functions, graphing-functions

Suppose I have two functions.

1. $$y= \frac{x^3+2x +9}{\sqrt{4x^2+3x+2}}$$
   which has an non linear asymptote of $y=\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{3x}{16}+\dfrac{251}{256}$.
2. $$y = \frac{x}{(x^4 + 1)^{1/4}}$$
   which has a linear asymptote of $y=1$.

How can I predict which function may have a non linear asymptote?

Comment: Forgive for the editing.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I have edited your question using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), check that I haven't made any errors, and also click edit to see how it works.

Comment: i think you meant $$\frac{x^3+2x+9}{\sqrt{4x^2+3x+2}}$$

Comment: @lioness99a thanx i appreciate your effort

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes there has been an error on this part :(

Comment: I will be learning mathJax real soon.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{x^4+1}}=\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt[4]{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}}$$